# In Pokemon Go, is there any benefits of catching an evolved Pokemon if you can going to transfer to the Professor anyway?

Tags: pokemon-go

For example, say I already got some Dratinis, and one Dragonair, and now, if I catch a Dratini versus if I catch a Dragonair, does it matter if I am going to transfer it to the Professor to get an extra candy to evolve my Dragonair to Dragonite?

That is, if I catch a Dratini and transfer, I get one Dratini candy, versus if I catch a Dragonair and transfer, I get one Dratini candy also?  So there is no extra benefits of catching a Dragonair vs a Dratini?

P.S. if so, a strategy can be, find out how many candies you need to evolve to a Dragonite first, and once you know it is 100, then when you have 25 candies, don't evolve to a Dragonair first, because if you catch one along the way, then the 25 candies you spent can be considered a waste.

Comment: +100 Stardust..

Answer (score 2):

No, not in your case -- a Dratini or Dragonair are the same thing to you, *unless* the Dragonair you catch is much stronger than your original one, or has better IVs. Catch it anyways, check the IVs, and then decide which one to transfer.

In response to your original question:

> In Pokemon Go, is there any benefits of catching an evolved Pokemon if you can going to transfer to the Professor anyway?

Yes, for the Pokedex entry. There are a lot of rather useless Pokemon out there (e.g. Venonat->Venomoth) that you shouldn't waste the time to collect candies for. Catching a Venomoth will allow you to throw away all your Venonats.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no extra benefit of catching the evolved form of a pokemon outside being able to spend less/no candies to evolve them. It takes less candies to evolve a dragonair into a dragonite than going from a dratini to a dragonite. You will always get 3 candies for catching and 1 candy for transferring for now. Might change in the future but as of now I have heard nothing about it.